# Is quantum uncertainty principle related to thermodynamics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, entropy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Would like to ask a question, but first i would like to say **Hello Everybody** in a way that plays the system, since some geniouses decided that one should not be able to say hello in a question.

The [uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) in quantum mechanics is well known and considered one of most basic properties of natural reality. The [2nd Law of thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) is also well known and also considered one of the most basic processes of natural reality.

The uncertainty principle uses and is related to [Planck's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant).
Planck's constant has the dimensions of *action* and in a statistical mechanics approach, also relates nicely with the partitioning of the phase-space providing the basic measure for the entropy functional ([this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/63325/44176) provides a nice outline of this).

Apart from that, there are [relatively recent papers](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.6894v1.pdf) which relate the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle in quantum mechanics directly and intuitively to the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics.

Is this relation correct? And if so can we derive one from the other?

Thank you

PS. One can also check [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60905/44176), which although not the same, is related in an interesting way.

UPDATE:

anna's answer is accepted since by mentioning the derivation of (part of) the 2nd law from unitary dynamics, answers the question at least in one way. Please consider this as still open so you can add another answer. There are more alternatives (and one of which is my stance, ie thermodynamics -> uncertainty)

Comment: Nikos, when you look at the PhysicsSE home page it shows just the first paragraph of your question i.e. just the complaint about not being able to say hello. It would increase the chance of your question being answered if you move the first paragraph to the end of your question.

Comment: @John, thank you very much for your comment and indeed it has a rationale (not seen so far in .se), however, isnt the title of the question supposed to be the shortest summary of the question itself? And additionally, lets not be "robots" in our communication, humour, phrasing, expression et al. in general can be half the fun :)

Comment: @John, and of course one always takes the responsibility for how to phrase the question and the associated results of not being answered fast or whatever, i would not like the editor to take away my hello if i want to say so. i dont talk to the editor i address people

Comment: @guntbert, i do not agree with the edit to remove the *chatty*, *unnecessary* beginning (aka a hello message with an edge indeed), and it does not seem to give me a way to undo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your self :

> The uncertainty principle in quantum mechanics is well known and considered one of most basic properties of natural reality.

In fact quantum mechanics and its postulates and laws are the underlying framework on which any classical theory is built.

The "laws" of classical theories emerge from the underlying quantum mechanical framework. In the paper you quote they claim that :

> More precisely, we show that violating the uncertainty relations in quantum mechanics leads to a thermodynamic cycle with positive net work gain, which is very unlikely to exist in nature.

As an experimentalist I am in no position to check whether their conclusion is correct, this is the work of peer review in journals, and it has been accepted in [Nature](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v4/n4/full/ncomms2665.html) and , I hope, peer reviewed. Well done if it is correct, because it is one more validation of the underlying quantum mechanical framework.

I do not know whether it is related to the statement in the wiki article :

> In statistical thermodynamics, the second law is a consequence of unitarity in quantum mechanics

It seems [from the references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics#cite_note-dewitt73-54) to be connected to the many worlds interpretation , so this new derivation might be a more mainstream connection of the quantum mechanical framework to the second law.

Comment: nice answer, thanks, although i do not favor the mainstream interpretation, specifically the Copenhagen interpretation and the ("artificial") fragmentation into "quantum" and "classical" worlds. So i try to find connections (and interpretations) in these directions, i think this is relevant. Nevertheless, i like the answer very much, will wait for any other answer, also

Comment: more specifically i tend towards quantum mechanics as a result of statistical mechanics (or sth like this), of course if they are equivalent (in some way), this makes things easier. On the other hand if this is the way it is , this is the way it is. No point involved in physics otherwise

Comment: Yes there is a result which "derives" the 2nd law from unitarity of the quantum formalism, however, can we go the other way? And moreover how about the measurement collapse and 2nd law? i think these are interesting by themselves but also, in what might be plausible quantum phenomena at large

Comment: There is also the time-asymetry of the 2nd law and the time-symmetric formalism of current quantum mechanics, There is a paper on an alternative formulation of quantum formalism (encompassing entropy), i can give the link if you like

Comment: i am also not a fan of many-worlds interpretation (for example it is not ergodic), but anyway, there are other interpretations which can also encompass the result (this is unfortunately not physics but sponsoring to a large extend)

Comment: let me explain a little more about ergodicity and the many-worlds interpretation, Assuming a quantum phenomenon as a dice experiment, the many-wolrds interpretation would generate 2 different worlds for different values of the dice (eg spin) and if this happens early (in some sense), then the other probability is never realized (ergodically) in the branch you are. i am not sure if EPR phenomena are taken into account also (i will have to check)

Comment: In my opinion one cannot go to quantum mechanics from thermodynamics, because thermodynamics is a meta level of  statistical mechanics and statistical mechanics is a meta level on quantum mechanics. One can find connections like in the paper you quote, but laws of thermodynamics stop being laws in statistical mechanics, like entropy, explainable by probabilities. One can explain analytically the higher level using the underlying level but one cannot go analytically to the lower level using the tools of the higher level.

Comment: anna, the [link](http://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0507/0507187.pdf) i was telling you previously, liked your comment

Comment: *"In fact quantum mechanics and its postulates and laws are the underlying framework on which any classical theory is built."* That is hardly a fact, since "quantum mechanics" was built partly based on classical mechanics. Even today, "quantum mechanics" is probabilistic theory and "classical theory" is not. Your claim seems as incorrect as "theory of hazard games is basis upon which statics of buildings is built".

Comment: @JánLalinský have a look at this http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html . a bit like how thermodynamics emerges from statistical mechanics.

Comment: As i posted on the other answer, Lochsmidts paradox still holds for interpretations to extract 2nd law from a "fundamental" QM (since QM or SM for that matter, is time-symmetric).

Comment: even if one takes into account decoherence?

Comment: hmmm, good one, decoherence, is again statistical. i would not like to argue this further, but just to be able to "convincingly" and "plausibly" defend another position. i would worry more on the QM side which has to solve the quantum measurement paradoxes, than thermodynamics which has a vast application (and **note** **does not** make assumptions about the nature of constituting elements **nor** of the scales, sth to ponder upon :) )

Comment: Look Nikos, at my age (74) I am to be allowed to have decided on my basic framework of physics, having worked professionally for 35 years and seen the standard model build up gradually. In my view it is QM that it is at the bottom the mathematics of nature and everything else emerges from it. Quantum measurement paradoxes are navel gazing by philosophically inclined theorists, again in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

That is a very nice question and the article (which I did not know) is interesting as it states that thermodynamics can't be true and the microscopic uncertainty relations false at the same time. Regardless of whether it's true or not, it is an interesting claim as it departs from the traditional wisdom of the full bottom-up approach.

I haven't checked whether the argument they put forward is sound or not but the way they do it is definitely reasonable for different reasons:

- If uncertainty relations have to do with thermodynamics, the link is likely to be at the *information* level. That is because, on the one hand, uncertainty relations imply that there exist such things as incompatible events which in turn says that the maximum amount of information we can have on a quantum system is a set of eigenvalues of a complete set of commuting observables. This information is seemingly always less than or equal to the classical information we could have on such a system. On the other hand, Landauer has proposed that the minimum amount of energy one has to give to change one bit of information is $k_BT \ln 2$ in order not to violate the second principle of thermodynamics. This limit is very important has it was a first reasonable solution to the Maxwell demon problem.
- At first glance, the authors of the paper seem to propose a thought experiment akin to the Maxwell's demon one but accounting for the quantum properties of the particles. From their reasoning they conclude that one can in principle obtain an infinite energy source (i.e. we would be back to the original problem of the Maxwell's demon) unless the uncertainty relations are true.

I still need to study more thoroughly the paper, but my take on it is that they have showed that one can seemingly violate the Landauer bound (and hence the second principle of thermodynamics) over one cycle if uncertainty relations are not enforced.

It has been shown [recently](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v483/n7388/full/nature10872.html) with a classical system that indeed one could violate the original Landauer bound in an erasure procedure of information. However, this does not violate a more elaborate version of the Landauer bound that takes into account the rate of success of the erasure protocol and I wonder if the result from Hanggi et al. could be interpreted in this broader context.

Unfortunately, I have no definite opinion neither about the work you point out not about the actual claim that thermodynamics implies uncertainty relations. But I do think that if it were to be true, then assessing the cost of information erasure would be the right direction to look into and also, in my view, how [fluctuation relations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6381) behave in the quantum world needs to be better understood to provide more definite arguments on this issue.

Comment: thanks for the article on fluctuation relations, will have to take a look at it

Comment: On the other hand an interpretation of uncertainty relations is exactly that the phase-space **cannot** be compressed arbitrarily (reality is indeed *real*), moreover information can also be derived itself. Regarding thermodynamics of computation (Landauer, Bennett et al), i (at least at present) do not consider whether it is based on erasure or on acquisition of information a problem, i think that both can be used equally well

Comment: Maxwell's daemon and variations (Szillard Engine, Szillard-Popper engine, etc..) are frequently used metaphors and frameworks in thermodynamic reasoning related to information. There are however objections (e.g [Norton's no-go reasoning](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/No_Go.pdf))

Comment: There was a recent paper on arxiv (circa 2012), that actually derived gravity from entropy and information reasoning (will have to find it, i have it somewhere)

Comment: The paper on fluctuations is quite good, has the math from the Clausius inequality,to Fokker-Planck and Path Integrals.However it is phrased and based on older/gloomy notions of entropy (heat death,disorder etc..). i suggest to look at Prigogine's work which is one of those to breath new life into the genre, and dispelling the myths of gloomy notions of entropy. Finally a more elementary analysis on entropy,fluctuations, etc.. on [another post of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734583/probabilistically-what-can-we-say-about-the-next-throw-of-a-coin-after-n-throws)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by older and gloomy but the way they talk about entropy seems fine to me especially when the topic is about extending thermodynamic concepts to the small world. It is true that uncertainty relations say that one cannot compress arbitrarily the phase space but that is more a consequence of their existence as annav was pointing out rather than them being necessary for thermodynamics to be consistent.

Comment: There is this interpretation of "entropy" (based on a mis-representation of the simplistic gas thermodynamic example) that entropy is this part of reality responsible for "(heat) death", "disorder", and other gloomy concepts, while all that is "good" in reality is quite the opposite and more "fundamental" or as a phenomenological and macroscopic-only property. This is sth which i have answered elsewhere (and i am not the only one, see also the comments on anna's answer). In a few words entropy is not that and certainly not only that.

Comment: As an answer to the fundamental nature of QM and 2nd law and entropy as a derivative of that. Lochsmidt's paradox still holds (QM remains time-symmetric etc..). This is at least implies much as to the status of the 2nd law (not to mention the vast area of application in many scales, including ours)

Comment: if you want another aspect of why this is considered this way (regarding thermodynamics). It goes back to the 18th century and the Newtonian paradigm as a prevailing one (and deterministic in a convinient sense). Similar things happened to Darwin, etc.. (Kuhn has taken a survey of some cases)

Comment: I am a bit lost now...what is your point of view exactly? Do you consider that thermodynamics implies QM or the way around? I still don't get what is the real good entropy (to oppose to the "gloomy" one) you talk multiple times about but without never saying explicitely what it is. And by the way, when it comes to Lochsmidt's paradox, I think Boltzmann already gave the right answer at  the time which has simply been (re)verified many times since then even in the quantum case as it has been shown [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2570.pdf) for example.

Comment: Actually yes this is my stance (that thermodynamics is more basic if you like) and that QM should (could) be derivable in these respects. However the main point of the question is an intimate relation between uncertainty and 2nd law (whichever way).

Comment: Ok, Prigogine's work and also the [Keenan-Hatzopoulos statement of the 2nd law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_N._Hatsopoulos) provide the different framework which answers your question (even more general statements can be made, but this is for another time)

Comment: In fact if Boltzmann in his attempt to derive explicitly what was considered the correct Maxwell distribution would not make extra requirements to, could derive sth very close to QM even before Planck and Heisenberg.

Comment: And since we continue on this line of thought. The mainstream treament of QM is a reductionist approach to build everything else on top. However Entropy is a holistic approach. This is related to philosophy of physics. But not forget that even Shroediger's equation is an axiom like Newton's equation (which it replaced) and not mre basic. It is a generalization of experience in a hypothesis. Much so the 2nd law (which has **not** been contradicted by any experiment, and there are many more than strictly QM experiments).