# Is uncertainty principle due to entropy?

Tags: entropy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Is uncertainty principle due to entropy or thermodynamics at all , I was wondering

Comment: Please edit your question with more supporting facts. Its is not at all clear why you base uncertainty principle on entropy.

Comment: It is asked before in this site, See here [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/115026/is-quantum-uncertainty-principle-related-to-thermodynamics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/115026/is-quantum-uncertainty-principle-related-to-thermodynamics)